# how to change the layout of storyboard from LTR to RTL in iOS without restart the application?

Tags: ios

```
NSArray* languages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:languages forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

This question looks incomplete, but I guess I can gather what you're trying to do.

In any case, this is not the recommended approach; overriding AppleLanguages is not supported by the system and will lead to many difficult-to-resolve edge cases.

Please fall back to the system language instead – this is very easy to do with NSLocalizedString, and Auto Layout does the right thing automatically without you having to do anything to your storyboard.